# Problem in view with sheet, button cannot be access

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-sheet

I created a view that has the sheet element and I disabled the option for it to be dismissed, but this led to the problem of the back button for the other view not being accessible.

[image of my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k18u.png)

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct PackDetailView: View {
    @State private var isShowingSheet = true
    var playlist: PlaylistModel

    var body: some View {
        Image(playlist.images)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                    
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingSheet) {
            ZStack {
                Color.primaryApp.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
                
                Text("\(playlist.title)")
            }
            .presentationDetents([.height(250), .height(720)])
            .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
            .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)       
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for this part of the view.

Comment: This is the built in behavior of `Sheet` and how Apple intend's it to work, you'll need to create a custom component if you want to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, sheets are modal which means that all interaction with the sheet behind is disabled.

You can alter this behaviour with the `presentationBackgroundInteraction` modifier (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/presentationbackgroundinteraction(_:)).

If you add `.presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)` then all UI elements, including the back button, will be useable.